# Cleaning up whitespace around strings without deleting spaces as well

Tags: php

So I currently have a series of strings. They might have access whitespaces so I want to get rid of it by turning "  book" into "book". However, if I use trim, a string such as "some title" becomes "sometitle". How do I go about this?

Comment: `trim("some title") !== "sometitle"` - [manual](http://www.php.net/trim)

Comment: @Jayson if your going to link to a function please use the php manual(http://php.net/trim) not that terrible site (this is why: http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Trim is the function you're looking for, documentation [here](https://www.php.net/trim). Contrary to what you're saying:

```
trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string
```

The middle will remain unaffected!

Answer (score 0):

```
$str[] = " book ";
$str[] = " book";
$str[] = "book ";
$str[] = "b o o k";
foreach($str as $s){
    echo trim($s).'<br>';
}
```

[trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) cuts before and after white space. never in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
trim(" Some title");
```

Won't remove the space in between words - only at the start and end of a string, ergo result:

```
"Some title"
```

There are also `ltrim()` and `rtrim()` functions, which remove chars from the left(start) and right(end) of a string respectively.

You can read more about them here:

- [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)
- [ltrim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)
- [rtrim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)